# Diagonal line through whole table

Tags: line, diagbox

I am trying to set up an intercorrelation table showing results of two samples. However, for better visuals, I want to split this table into two parts by adding a diagonal line through whole table (not only one cell). The cells themselves have different lengths.

I actually tried to use diagbox, but it failed, (afaik) because it's only intended to be applied at one cell only.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{diagbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{rrrrrr}
    \toprule \\[-1.8ex] 
    & AAAAA & BBBBBBBB & CCCCC & DDDDDD & EEEEEE \\ 
    \midrule
    A & \backslashbox && && \\ 
    B & .XX***  &  \backslashbox & &  & \\ 
    C & .XX***  & .XX***  & \backslashbox & & \\ 
    D & .XX***  & .XX***  & .XX***  & \backslashbox &\\ 
    E & .XX***  & .XX***  & .XX***  & .XX***  & \backslashbox \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Any ideas - I checked existing answers but none seems to fit.

Comment: You can do it in [picture mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/438916/134574)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possibility with `pstricks`, if I've well understood what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{pst-node, auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{postscript}
\begin{tabular}{rrrrrr}
    \toprule \\[-1.8ex]
    & AAAAA & BBBBBBBB & CCCCC & DDDDDD & EEEEEE \\
    \midrule
    A \pnode[1em, 2.6ex]{A} & && && \\
    B & .XX*** & & & & \\
    C & .XX*** & .XX*** & & & \\
    D & .XX*** & .XX*** & .XX*** & &\\
    E & .XX*** & .XX*** & .XX*** & .XX*** & \pnode[0.6em, -1.3ex]{X} \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\ncline[linewidth = 0.4pt]{A}{X}
\end{postscript}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's a quite good solution, perfect! However, using TeXStudio and trying to compile this, it results in an error (Package auto-pst-pdf Error: . Or turn off auto-pst-pdf.}). If I set it on XeLaTeX, it works but then other issues occur (wrong signs etc.)

Comment: I compiled this with xelatex. Did you obtain these wrong signs with exactly this code?

Comment: yes, but in the whole document, not in this table - sorry, if this is offtopic!

Comment: Could ypu post a minimal (yet complete) code reproducing your problems?

Comment: I will try this tomorrow! Thanks so far for your help!

Comment: I solved it - there were issues due to switch from pdfLaTeX to XeLaTeX.. hence, your solution works perfektly! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. That environment is similar to the classical environment `{tabular}` (of the package `array`) but creates also PGF/Tikz under the cells, rows and columns. It's possible to use those nodes to draw whatever rule you want with Tikz in the `\CodeAfter`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{rrrrrr}
\toprule
& AAAAA & BBBBBBBB & CCCCC & DDDDDD & EEEEEE \\
\midrule
A \\
B & .XX*** \\
C & .XX*** & .XX*** \\
D & .XX*** & .XX*** & .XX*** \\
E & .XX*** & .XX*** & .XX*** & .XX*** & \\
\bottomrule
\CodeAfter
  \tikz \draw (2-|2) -- (last-|last) ; 
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because of the PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]

In fact, you can also draw your diagonal line with the command `\diagbox` (a built-in command of `nicematrix`) in a command `\Block` (which is also a built-in command of `nicematrix`). With this technic, you don't have to use explicitely TikZ.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{rrrrrr}
\toprule
& AAAAA & BBBBBBBB & CCCCC & DDDDDD & EEEEEE \\
\midrule
A & \Block{*-*}{\diagbox{}{}}\\
B & .XX*** \\
C & .XX*** & .XX*** \\
D & .XX*** & .XX*** & .XX*** \\
E & .XX*** & .XX*** & .XX*** & .XX*** & \\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

The output is the same.